# Run whole Rails application in a single process (Apache + Phusion Passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, apache, passenger

When running a Rails application in Apache + Phusion Passenger it turns out that Apache starts initializers and page requests in different processes.

Are there ways to force it to run whole application in one process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you use Phusion Passenger Enterprise, you can set `PassengerMaxInstances 1`, forcing it to use only 1 process. Then you set `PassengerConcurrencyModel thread` and `PassengerThreadCount x`, forcing it to spawn x threads inside that single process.

Comment: any guidance on how better is threads over single? like you can improve performance on X %